# How can I make a fixed distance joint(no rotation) in box2d?

Tags: box2d

I want to make objectB's movement exactly the same with objectA's. So I use a distance joint connect objectB with objectA. But when objectA flies, the joint will rotate,then objectB will move later. How can I make they move at same time and in same way?

Answer (score 0):

If you want them to act exactly the same the best idea is not to create joint but **create more than one fixture** for one body.

```
    Body body;

    ...

    FixtureDef fixtureDef1 = new FixtureDef();
    FixtureDef fixtureDef2 = new FixtureDef();


    Fixture fixture1 = body.createFixture(fixtureDef1);
    Fixture fixture2 = body.createFixture(fixtureDef2);

    fixture1.setUserDate("FIRST");
    fixture1.setUserDate("SECOND");
```

Then you can handle all collisions etc using their UserData objects.

---

If there is any reason you cannot define it at the beginning you can try with creating both **Distance** and **Prismatic** joints but I'm really not sure if it will work - many times I've faced the situation when joints were behaving really weird when I was using for example **setTransform** on body.

To read more about types of joints [visit this page](http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/joints-overview) and take a look at the [official reference of Box2d](http://www.box2d.org/manual.html#_Toc258082974)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried to use b2WeldJoint which doesn't work on b2_kinematicBody as bodyB. I would take your advice to make it.